# How many ways can n+1 distinguishable objects be placed into n indistinguishable boxes, so that no box is empty?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

I've been having a really hard time coming up with a closed form formula for this. Solutions online all use Stirling numbers which my course has not covered. Right now what I have is [((n-1)^n) - ((n-2)^n) -... ((n-k)^n) ]/(n-1)! tbh I dont know if it is even right

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you have to choose are the two items that share a box.  Once you have that, you have to put one item in every other box and you don't care which box each one goes in.

Comment: So does C(n, n) + n make sense? Sorry I'm not getting it and the videos I've watched on it dont make a ton of sense to me

Comment: No, that just gives $1+n$.  You can choose the first of the pair in $n+1$ ways and the second in $n$ ways, but have counted every pair twice for the two orders.  This gives $\frac 12n(n+1)=C(n+1,2)$.  This is the number of ways to choose two items out of $n+1$

Comment: Okay that makes sense to be but I just want to clarify C(n+1, 2) would just be the final answer. I was thinking C(n-1, (n-1) - (n-1)) to be multiplied because there are n-1 balls left and n-1 spaces but that would obviously void the result.

Comment: Yes, it is.  Note that your last works out to $C(n-1,0)=1$ so we can multiply by it if we want.